# Convert int to char array ("string")

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, int

I am new to C. I have a struct employee like follows:-

```
struct employee
{
    char eid[100];
    char name[100];
};
```

I want to assign this eid value as "EMP_1", "EMP_2" and so on. Whenever any employee enters its name its id should be generated dynamically like "EMP_1" for the first employee and "EMP_2" for the second employee. But i am not able to understand how to add an integer value to a char. 
I have tried like this

```
struct employee e;
char emp[20]="EMP_";
char id=(char)i; //Here i will be representing the number of employee like 1st or 2nd.
strcat(emp,id);
e.id=emp;
```

But it is not working. Any other suggestions how to assign "EMP_1" "EMP_2" etc value to id of struct.

Comment: 1) there is a semicolon missing after you struct definition. 2) what is `struct emp` ? 3) `char[100] eid;` -->> `char eid[100];`

Comment: @wildplasser struct employee is a structure of employee type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you define string `eid` quite large, I think using `sprintf` is simply enough.

```
struct employee e;
int id=1; //Here i will be representing the number of employee like 1st or 2nd.
sprintf(e.eid,"EMP_%d",id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`snprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html).

```
snprintf(emp.eid, sizeof emp.eid, "%s%d", "EMP_", id);
```

Comment: after this the type of emp.id will be of string type ?

Comment: if we want to print its value then we will use printf("%s",emp.id); ??

Comment: `emp.eid` always has type `char [100]`. Once defined like that it never changes. To print it, you usage is correct.